# Sorting a column of table in Javascript not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, html-table

I have the following Javascript function from w3schools to sort a column:

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
    /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
    and mark that a switch has been done:*/
    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
    switching = true;
    //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
    switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However it doesn't work well on my column called Internet Explorer Version.

It works well with other columns of my table. I don't know why this is happening. Can someone just tell me what's going wrong?

I copied these values on an excel sheet and tried to sort it, but it doesn't sort properly as well. Is it an issue with the values?

It is just taking the first digit of the number into consideration and then sorting. How can I fix this?

Comment: @sauntimo could you please help?

Comment: post your table

Comment: not picture but html code

Comment: `document.write()` writes over everything. Do not use it. Since you are parsing string into HTML, use `innerHTML` or even better [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://learnwebcoding.com/javascript/javascript_reference/insertAdjacentHTML_method.php)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short create padding with `100000`, for example

```
8.00.6001.18372 => 100008.100000.106001.118372
11.0.15063.0 => 100011.100000.115063.100000
```

with regex

```
x = x.innerHTML.replace(/\d+/g, n => +n + 100000);
```

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  // get longest version characters for padding
  var padding = '000000000000'; // 12 chars
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      // the hack, remove dot      
      x = x.innerHTML.replace(/\d+/g, n => +n + 100000);
      y = y.innerHTML.replace(/\d+/g, n => +n + 100000);
     //console.log(x)
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x > y) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x < y) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector('#thead').addEventListener('click', function() {
  sortTable(0);
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 60%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background-color: #209d9d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

th:hover {
  background-color: #1c8d8d;
}

tr {
  height: 30px;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  align: center
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr><th id="thead">IE Versions</th></tr>
  <tr><td>10.0.8250.00000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10.0.8400.00000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10.0.9200.16384</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8.00.6001.18372</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8.00.6001.18702</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8.00.7000.00000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8.00.7600.16385</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9.0.8080.16413</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9.0.8112.16421</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10.0.9200.17609</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11.0.15063.0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11.0.9600.18697</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8.00.6001.18241</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The result is correct as per string operation comparison rule, but your requirement is different.

How string comparison happen ?
A < B

1. It compare UTF-16 value from  first digit of both string if it is equal then compare next character.
2. If character of A's string at some point less than B then A String will be smaller.
3. If any of string will end before reaching conclusion It will be consider as small string.

for example

1. "10.0.9200.17609" < "11.0.15063.0" = true because on 2nd digit 0 < 1
2. "9" < "101" = false because  UTF-16 value of '9' is greater than '1'
3. "101" < "1011" = true because till 3 char both are equal and first string ends So It is smaller.

For your problem you need to split your numbers on .(dot)
for example "10.0.9200.17609" after split [10, 0, 9200, 17609]
then you need to use following comparator function to decide which element is smaller in your sort algorithm.

```
/** 
  A and B will be array and element are integer
  return true if A < B else false
**/
function comparator(A, B) {
   var a_length = A.length, b_length = B.length;
   var loop_count = min(a_length, b_length);
   for(var i = 0; i < loop_count; i++) {
     if(A[i] < B[i])
        return true;
     else if (A[i] > B[i])
        return false;
   }

   if(a_length < b_length)
     return true;

   return false;
}
```

Comment: So, how and where do I integrate this onto my code?

Comment: x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() <  y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() before comparing it, do var X =   x.innerHTML.split('.') and var Y = y.innerHTML.split('.'); and then comparator(X < Y) in place of x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() <  y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()

Comment: JavaScript uses the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set, not ASCII. (Java, .NET, VB6,…, too).

Comment: yeah you are correct, but Unicode is a superset of ASCII, and the numbers 0–128 have the same meaning in ASCII as they have in Unicode